# Changing the speed on an open serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change SerialPort's BaudRate while connection is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814829/change-serialports-baudrate-while-connection-is-open)

I know how to open, close, and set up the baud rate for the port, etc, but while the port is still open I want to change the baud rate from 9600 to 115200.

I Googled it and it said that it could be done by issuing the command to set the port baud rate (e.g. serialport.baurate = 115200).  However, it did not work consistently for me and I wondered if I missed something.

Could someone illustrate the proper way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Getting the device on the other end of the wire to switch the baudrate at the same time takes a miracle or two.  At the very least you'll have to wait until BytesToWrite drops to 0 and add 16 * 10 / baudrate seconds to ensure the fifo is flushed.

Comment: M.Babcock, it treats the same issue, yet the "accepted" reply on the one you link does not shed any light. How can I say it... is very unhelpful (no offense intended).

Comment: The most appropriate answer was not selected as *the answer* to that question. See [Groo's response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5814866/635634) which is effectively the same as Hans' comment above.

Comment: can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64203396/6854117) related to it?